# Swift App Locking Permission? Other Application?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, locking, passcode

I'm trying to make an app which blocks the permission to other apps (first need to be unlocked via a code which well be set up in my app).

For that I'd need some guidance and resources. I looked through the App Dev catalog and haven't found anything related - github no source codes, but still there are working apps which block e.g. the photo app or Instagram or alike.

Comment: You have to look at building an MDM.  You can't do it on device only

Comment: Are Mobile-Device Management apps possible with the normal Swift-syntax (ios Store)? Haven't seen any permissions regarding this? Might you link me some resources or submit a "solution" to this questions: Which permissions are needed? Resources / Links / Syntax?

Comment: Most of the work is done by a server.  Any iOS app is just for administration of policies etc.  You need a special entitlement from Apple; There is a specific clause in the App Store review guidelines about it

Comment: So as a normal App developer I won't have the necessary permissions to do such an app?

Comment: If you have an organisational membership of the developer program you can apply.  If you are an individual you cannot apply